# Hibernate - two sub-classes of the same type in a mapping

Tags: java, json, hibernate, rest, jersey

I have working on a RESTful application (Jersey) using json (with Gson, from Google) for get and send the data. For persistence, I'm using Hibernate. In next lines, I will put some code as an example (it's not the real data!).

I have a relation between two classes, as follows:

```
public class A {
    private Long id;
    private B fieldB1;
    private B fieldB2;
}
```

(It is assumed that the class has getters and setters.)

The mapping file is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.app.A" table="A">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
            <column name="ID" unique="true"/>
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="fieldB1" class="com.app.B" fetch="join">
            <column name="FIELDB1" />
        </many-to-one>
        <many-to-one name="fieldB2" class="com.app.B" fetch="join">
            <column name="FIELDB2" />
        </many-to-one>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I try to send a request to the REST service in the server (now i'm using Postman from Google) in order to get an **A** object by id, **converted to JSON**, the following 4 scenarios occur:

> 1. If fieldB1 and fieldB2 are null, the json object I receive doesn't have fieldB1 and fieldB2 in the body.
> 2. If only fieldB2 is null, the json object I receive has fieldB1 but doesn't have fieldB2 in the body.
> 3. If fieldB1 and fieldB2 have data (that is, both are not null), I obtain this exception: **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>      Attempted to serialize java.lang.Class:
>      org.hibernate.proxy.HibernateProxy. Forgot to register a type
>      adapter?**
> 4. If fieldB1 is null but fieldB2 are not null, item n° 3 occurs.

As I see, the problem appears with the second class **B** in the mapping. So?

Comment: The classes are not the same type. One is ar.com.B and the other is com.app.B.

Comment: Sorry, this is a mistake... i will fix it now .. the correct type is **com.app.B**

Comment: It seems that Hibernate is lazy-loading the second instance of `B`, thus Jackson is not able to serialize it (because it still is a proxy when the serializer kicks in). You may need to add https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate to your project. I don't know why the first one is not lazy loaded though.